# Calculating Polynomial Regression of Dynamic Dataset in Microsoft Access (similar to LINEST in Excel)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Dataset in Microsoft Access for Amperage and Lumens (seen below in the first image). This list can be of any length of rows. This example happens to be three, but it can be as many as 10+ rows or more. I want to calculate the polynomial regression so I can have another dataset table (second image) where the user can input their "Lumen Targets" and automatically populate the "Target Amperage". I am open to suggestions on a different route for this. The overall form is a top product with multiple configurations. Each configuration has different sizes and amperages/lumen levels. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

[image: Access Example]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking?  Do you know the formula to do this manually and need help automating it, or do you need help with the formula?

Comment: I have the table in the first image (Amperage [220, 350, 450] vs Lumens []630, 940, 1140), let's call that table1. I want to take the linear regression of table1 and use that to determine the Amperage in Table2 (second image with Lumen Targets = 500, 700, 900, 1100, 1300) at the user inputed Targets of 500, 700, 900, etc. The result is Table2 Amperage automatically calculated from the regression formula. Did that help? Or did I just make it worse...

Comment: Ha!  Still not sure if you need help with formula or implementing it.  see this...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238410.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking, however if you want to calculate the linear regression (e.g. slope of the line given the known x's/y's) you can call a worksheet function.  Make sure you have a reference to 'Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library' in VBA and create a function where you can pass your known values in order to return the slope.

```
Public Function Slope(x, y)
Slope = WorksheetFunction.Slope(x, y)
End Function
```